# How can I add a unique value "true" for all the rows ina table?

Tags: sql, h2, unique-constraint

I'm creating a database with H2, and one of the tables, call group, has one attribute call "default".

So, for this table, It can be only one default column, the others has to be false, is there a way to define that constrain in SQL H2? or I ahve to do it by Java code?

Comment: I am confused by this entirely.  How can `'true'` be *unique* if it is the same in all rows of a table?

Comment: It can be only one row with value "true", the rest of the rows should be false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CHECK` constraint with a subquery.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    F BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD CHECK
    NOT F OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT T2.ID FROM TEST T2 WHERE T2.ID <> TEST.ID AND T2.F
    );
```

However, such constraints with subqueries in H2 can be unsafe if the table can be modified by multiple sessions at the same time; it depends on the settings.